# Сервер получает ObejctInputStream и кидает ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер

Есть клиент и сервер. Клиент отправляет пакет me.nyanguymf.console.net.Packet серверу через ObjectOutputStream:

```
/** Sends request to server. */
public boolean sendRequest(Packet request) {
    try {
        out.writeObject(request);
        out.flush();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Сервер принимает этот объект:

```
if (super.isInterrupted())
    break;

Object obj = null;
try {
    try {
        obj = in.readObject();
    } catch (SocketException expected) {
        System.err.println("Lost connection");
        break;
    }

    if (!(obj instanceof Packet))
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();

    Packet packet = (Packet) obj;

    System.out.println("Got clients packet: " + packet.toString());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException expected) {
    System.err.println("Got invalid object from server. Is it up to date?");
    expected.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Но вылезает ошибка ClassNotFoundException:

```
Got invalid object from server. Is it up to date?
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.nyanguymf.console.net.Packet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:686)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at me.nyanguymf.console.server.net.InputThread.run(InputThread.java:38)
```

Этот самый класс скомпилировал (вместе с остальными необходимыми) в отдельную .jar библиотеку и подключил её через Maven:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>me.nyanguymf.console.net</groupId>
    <artifactId>Packet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/PacketLib.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Что может быть не так, почему вылезает ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, помогло удаление строки

```
if (!(obj instanceof Packet))
    throw new ClassNotFoundException();
```

Но я не могу понять: почему obj не является экемпляром Packet, если отправляется именно он и на следующей строке приведение к типу Packet не вызывает ошибку?

Comment: Возможно obj загружен другим класслоадером.

Comment: @AndreySmelik, вау, не знал, что такое может быть :D Не подскажете, где можно подробнее изучить эту тему?

Comment: Да любую хорошую статью про класслоадеры почитать, я сам если честно не особо хорошо в этом разбираюсь. https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/646-kak-proiskhodit-zagruzka-klassov-v-jvm